# How to get SecurityToken from ClaimsPrincipal?

Tags: .net, authentication, identity, claims-based-identity, federated-identity

How to get `SecurityToken` from `ClaimsPrincipal`?

I need it because I wanna pass it from an MVC application to a WCF service in [AuthenticationManager / Authenticate](http://www.terrymarshall.com.au/Blog/tabid/162/EntryId/146/Identity-Management-in-Net-4-5-Part-7-Token-Processing-Pipeline.aspx).

In Authenticate method, the value BootstrapContext is null. And even after authenticating, it is getting null sometimes which make it a not reliable choice for me.

This is my Authentication Manager class:

```
public override ClaimsPrincipal Authenticate(string resourceName, ClaimsPrincipal incomingPrincipal)
{
    string passportID = incomingPrincipal.Identity.GetPassportID().ToString();

    try
    {
        // I need the token here 
        SecurityToken token = GetToken(incomingPrincipal);
        return base.Authenticate(resourceName, incomingPrincipal);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new SecurityException("User is not authenticated.", ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using this code:

```
BootstrapContext context = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First().BootstrapContext as BootstrapContext;
SecurityToken token = context.SecurityToken;

if (context.SecurityToken != null)
{
    token = context.SecurityToken;
}
else if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(context.Token) == false)
{
    var handlers = FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers;
    token = handlers.ReadToken(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(context.Token)));
}

var actAsToken = GetActAsToken(token);
```

You can read more about it in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514553/wif-4-5-bootstrapcontext-security-token-null) SO question. It seems that `context.SecurityToken` will in some time be cleared so one can not depend on it too much.

Comment: Thanks pepo.. Just wondering if there is a way I can get the GetActAsToken from the IdP without generating it locally again.

I'm using Thinktecture.

Comment: I stored the ActAs token in a memory cache. I set the expiration of the object (token) in cache some time before actual token expiration. Then, if I did not find the ActAs token for some user, I requested it again from IdP. It worked well for me and to this day I did not have any problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<identityConfiguration saveBootstrapContext="true">
```

This will save the bootstrap token in ClaimsPrincipal.BootstrapContext.